# Find CRLF in Files Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to check if a text file contains unix style line endings (LF) or windows style line endings (CR LF). As you know , Add-Content appends a trailing CRLF, which is undesired.
My question is : First condition is : if text file contains CRLF (Windows-style) line endings and/or LF-only (Unix-style) so the last line had cr/lf  then it will not be add new line in script.

Second condition is : if text file not contains contains CRLF (Windows-style) line endings and/or LF-only (Unix-style) then it will insert an extra CR/LF at the end of file like below. so that added the new line of text with a cr/lf at the end of the file.

BTW, I am using Powershell v4.

1 - For example :first condition is   :

```
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
```

after adding windows line endings:

```
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=TESTTEXT CRLF
```

2 - For example :second condition is   :

Before adding the last line had NO cr/lf :

```
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER
```

after adding windows line endings:

```
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=SQLSERVER CRLF
jdbc/PIKYDNC=TESTTEXT CRLF
```

Here is my code :

```
$get_source = get-content "C:\Deneme\test-source.txt"
$get_source | foreach {
    if ($_ -eq $get_source[0]){ #To start on a new line at the beginning of the import
        add-content -Value "`n$_" -path "C:\Deneme\test-dest.txt"
        add-content -Value "`n$_" -path "C:\Deneme\test-dest3.txt"
        $cnt = $get_source[0]
        $cnt1 = $cnt.split('=')[1]
        $cnt2 = $cnt1 + "=SQLSERVER"
        add-content -Value "$cnt2" -path "C:\Deneme\test-dest4.txt"
    }
    else{
        Add-Content -Value "`n$_" -Path "C:\Deneme\test-dest2.txt"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're facing. `Get-Content` splits the file it reads at newlines (unless called with the parameter `-Raw`), so all you need to do is write the data you read back to a file with `Set-Content` (which adds CRLF at the end of each line, including the last one), then `Add-Content` the lines you want appended.

Comment: Thanks man. could you please send me sample script regarding `Set-content` ?

Comment: `Get-Content input.txt | Set-Content output.txt` if you're writing to a different file. `(Get-Content file.txt) | Set-Content file.txt` if you're writing to the same file.